# What I will do if my .jar file can not run outside the "dist" folder?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have made a Stopwatch for my personal interest using JFrame Form in Netbeans. Then I made a .jar file. I follwed the instructions stated below.

```
1. Right-click on the Project name.
2. Select Properties.
3. Click Packaging.
4. Check Build JAR after Compiling.
5. Check Compress JAR File.
6. Click OK to accept changes.
7. Right-click on a Project name.
8. Select Build or Clean and Build.
```

I found the .jar file on the `dist` folder of the project folder. It runs well there. But when I move this to other directory outside the project folder, it doesn't run.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: And what is the exact issue? Any exceptions with stack traces?

Comment: “it doesn't run.”  How can you tell?  What did you do in order to run it?

Comment: What else is on the dist folder? I suspect there are other (probably jar) files. If so, you need to move those too with the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue. The problem is external libraries' path is not valid outside of /dist folder. So we need to pack